# Seekbar issue in playing song form raw

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to play audio from res/raw/filename.mp3 . I learn from online tutorials and create this code .It is playing,pausing,stopping without any disturbances but seek bar is not working properly. Its moving but I want to do forward and rewind use by seek bar.When i drag the seek bar,it is follow and moving after that go back to current playing time. I have to solve this issue ,Please help me how should i do? Thanks in advance.

Java Code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   public TextView songName,startTimeField,endTimeField;
   private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
   private double startTime = 0;
   private double finalTime = 0;
   private Handler myHandler = new Handler();;
   private int forwardTime = 5000; 
   private int backwardTime = 5000;
   private SeekBar seekbar;
   private ImageButton playButton,pauseButton;
   public static int oneTimeOnly = 0;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      songName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
      startTimeField =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      endTimeField =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
      seekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
      playButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
      pauseButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
      songName.setText("Thingyan songs.mp3");
      mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.nn);
      seekbar.setClickable(false);
      pauseButton.setEnabled(false);


   }

   @SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void play(View view){
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing sound", 
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      mediaPlayer.start();
      finalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
      startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
      if(oneTimeOnly == 0){
         seekbar.setMax((int) finalTime);
         oneTimeOnly = 1;
      } 


         endTimeField.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec", 
         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) finalTime),
         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) finalTime) - 
         TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
         toMinutes((long) finalTime)))
      );
      startTimeField.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec", 
         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) - 
         TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
         toMinutes((long) startTime)))
      );
      seekbar.setProgress((int)startTime);

      myHandler.postDelayed(UpdateSongTime,100);
      pauseButton.setEnabled(true);
      playButton.setEnabled(false);
   }

   private Runnable UpdateSongTime = new Runnable() {
      @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void run() {
         startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
         startTimeField.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec", 
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) - 
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
            toMinutes((long) startTime)))
         );
         seekbar.setProgress((int)startTime);
         myHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
      }
   };
   public void pause(View view){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pausing sound", 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      mediaPlayer.pause();
      pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
      playButton.setEnabled(true);
   }    
   public void forward(View view){
      int temp = (int)startTime;
      if((temp+forwardTime)<=finalTime){
         startTime = startTime + forwardTime;
         mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) startTime);
      }
      else{
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
         "Cannot jump forward 5 seconds", 
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

   }
   public void rewind(View view){
      int temp = (int)startTime;
      if((temp-backwardTime)>0){
         startTime = startTime - backwardTime;
         mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) startTime);
      }
      else{
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
         "Cannot jump backward 5 seconds",
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }



}


   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   return true;


   }



 }`
```

Xml code:

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="300dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="350dp"
        android:onClick="rewind"
        android:src="@drawable/leftone" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_x="250dp"
        android:layout_y="350dp"
        android:onClick="forward"
        android:src="@drawable/rightone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="160dp"
        android:layout_y="18dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="165dp"
        android:layout_y="350dp"
        android:onClick="play"
        android:src="@drawable/playfive" />

    <ImageButton
        android1:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_x="85dp"
        android1:layout_y="350dp"
        android1:onClick="pause"
        android1:src="@drawable/pauseone" />

    <Button
        android1:id="@+id/button1"
        android1:layout_width="150dp"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_x="0dp"
        android1:layout_y="430dp"
        android1:text="" />

    <TextView
        android1:id="@+id/textView1"
        android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_x="30dp"
        android1:layout_y="445dp"
        android1:text="@string/inital_Time"
        android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Button
        android1:id="@+id/button2"
        android1:layout_width="150dp"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_x="170dp"
        android1:layout_y="430dp"
        android1:text="" />

    <TextView
        android1:id="@+id/textView2"
        android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_x="200dp"
        android1:layout_y="445dp"
        android1:text="@string/inital_Time"
        android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android1:id="@+id/textView3"
        android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_x="30dp"
        android1:layout_y="15dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android1:text="@string/hello_world"
        android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android1:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android1:layout_width="match_parent"
        android1:layout_height="238dp"
        android1:layout_x="0dp"
        android1:layout_y="62dp"
        android1:src="@drawable/water" />

    <TextView
        android1:id="@+id/textView5"
        android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_x="200dp"
        android1:layout_y="475dp"
        android1:text="Total Duration" />

    <TextView
        android1:id="@+id/textView6"
        android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_x="40dp"
        android1:layout_y="475dp"
        android1:text="Playing Time" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: you can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html to notify seekbar is changed

Answer (score 0):

you need `SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener`:

```
YOUR_CLASS implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{
    ......................
    ......................

    seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // Important  

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
            int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(UpdateSongTime);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        myHandler.removeCallbacks(UpdateSongTime);

        int currentPosition = seekBar.getProgress();

        // forward or backward to certain seconds
        mp.seekTo(currentPosition);

        // update timer progress again
        myHandler.postDelayed(UpdateSongTime,100);
    }
}
```